# Careers profiles should onebox in chat, but they don't

Tags: feature-request, jobs, chat, onebox

Careers profiles should [onebox in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6691624#6691624).

I am not sure of anything else that I could add, but since regular Stack Exchange profiles onebox in chat, so should the careers profiles.

Comment: Hehe thanks @Lance I was feeling a bit dyslexic today....